# SVG in KV lang file

Tags: svg, kivy, kivy-language

I'm looking to use an SVG in Kivy, but I'd prefer to do so in a kv file, as opposed to in the py program. However, when I try something such as

```
Widget:
    canvas.before:
        Svg:
            filename: "mySVGFile.svg"
```

I get an ``**init**() takes at least 1 positional argument". How can I use an SVG from the kv file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like because Svg requires at least one positional argument, it cannot currently be used from kv alone. Feel free to raise an issue about that on the Kivy github page, I don't think there's any real reason for it.

Comment: Yeah, that's the feeling that I was getting.

Answer (score 1):

Currently

```
Widget:
    canvas.before:
        Svg:
            source: "mySVGFile.svg"
```

Works fine.